# extending existing functions (student's t-test)

Tags: r, function

I am trying to get the Student's t-test, however not only using the t.test function, but extending it.

so far,

```
x<- c(16.6,13.4,14.6,15.1,12.9,15.2,14.0,16.6,15.4,13.0)
y<- c(15.8,17.9,18.2,20.2,18.1,17.8,18.3,18.6,17.0,18.4)

ttest <- function(x,y) {
  n1<- length(y)       #y length
  n2<- length(x)       #x length
  somay <- sum(y)
  somax <- sum(x)
  y1 <- (somay)/n1       #y mean
  y2<- (somax)/n2        #x mean
  dadosy <- na.omit(y)
  dadosx <- na.omit(x)
  disvquad1 <- (dadosy-y1)^2
  disvquad2 <- (dadosx-y2)^2
  s12<- (1/(n1-1))*sum(disvquad1)    #variance of y
  s22<- (1/(n2-1))*sum(disvquad2)    #variance of x
  s2 <- ((n1-1)*s12+(n2-1)*s22)/((n1-1)+(n2-1))
  s<- (s2)^(1/2)
  t<- (y1-y2)/((1/n1)+(1/n2))^(1/s)     #test statistic 
  return(t)
}
> ttest(x,y)
[1] 12.22666
```

however, when i run the t.test function with this arguments i receive a different value:

```
> t.test(x,y)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -6.0257, df = 17.425, p-value = 1.227e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.520774 -2.179226
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
    14.68     18.03
```

*t= -6.0257*  **!=**  *t= 12.22666*

any ideas why am i receiving different values? thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you been through all the different option that `t.test` has, like `var.equal = FALSE` and `alternative = "two.sided"`? You should figure out which set of options corresponds to what you're trying to implement in your own code before you stress about differences in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for the test statistic is wrong. It should be

```
ttest <- function(x,y) {
n1<- length(y)       #y length
n2<- length(x)       #x length
somay <- sum(y)
somax <- sum(x)
y1 <- (somay)/n1       #y mean
y2<- (somax)/n2        #x mean
dadosy <- na.omit(y)
dadosx <- na.omit(x)
disvquad1 <- (dadosy-y1)^2
disvquad2 <- (dadosx-y2)^2
s12<- (1/(n1-1))*sum(disvquad1)    #variance of y
s22<- (1/(n2-1))*sum(disvquad2)    #variance of x
s2 <- ((n1-1)*s12+(n2-1)*s22)/((n1-1)+(n2-1))
s<- (s2)^(1/2)
t<- (y1-y2)/(sqrt(1/n1+1/n2)*s)     #test statistic 
return(t)
}

> ttest(x,y)
[1] 6.025747

> t.test(y,x)

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y and x
t = 6.0257, df = 17.425, p-value = 1.227e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
2.179226 4.520774
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
18.03     14.68
```